# Is there any quick way that I can select method code block in vim

Tags: vim

For example, that's a really common situation that I want to select all method code block for **search**,is there anyway to do that ?

```
    search(key){
    this._dataSet=this._userOriginSet.filter(r=>r.map.NickName || 
    r.map.Name)
              .filter(r=>{
                if(r.map.NickName){
                  return r.map.NickName.indexOf(key.trim())>-1
                }
                if(r.map.Name){
                  return r.map.Name.indexOf(key.trim())>-1
                }
              });
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

with your cursor inside the method type `Va{`. now depending on where your cursor was positioned you won't get the full code block. Type `a{` another few times to expend the selection till you get what you need.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: May be, your answer also should mention text-objects and explain how u got `Va{` @sudavid4